# Select Case only seeing one digit

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

[image]

Picture of problem. Instead of looking at the value of the TextBox which is 20 is returning 2 which is the first digit of the 2 digit number in the textbox

------------------//--------------------

Select case only looking at 1 digit.

I have a case function running through some numbers and its supposed to change textcolour if value is over 4, or over 3 or over 2 or over 1

It works fine for numbers up to 9, but when the numbers start having more than a single digit it only looks at the first digit. Code below:

```
For Each TextStatas In Arr_TextStat

        Select Case TextStatas.Text
            Case > 4
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.Green

            Case > 3
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow

            Case > 2
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.Gold

            Case > 1
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange

            Case > 0
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.Red

            Case 0
                TextStatas.BackColor = Color.Red

        End Select
    Next
```

I use a similar piece of code on a different form, connected to the same database and looking at the same table and column as this form, but in there it works fine.

Can't understand what's wrong!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Turn on option strict.  Do not infer data types.  Try : Select Case CInt(TextStatas.Text)

Comment: Should start from smallest to largest then. Rookie mistake. I was doing the exact opposite. Makes me wonder though why its working well on another form in the same project.

Comment: @OMGSOMETAL I cannot reproduce your issue. The code is working fine (and you certainly should not rearrange from smallest to largest otherwise it will be all red).

Comment: It is all red as @GSerg mentioned...I'll update my question with a picture of the breakpoint where the problem happens

Comment: @GSerg Updated.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a new project with just one textbox on a form?

Comment: I will try. Something occurred to me though, on the other form I have I'm not using .text to assign a value and read a value, I'm using .tag. Will try that first on this form to see if it makes a change.

Comment: @GSerg Sorted! seems the problem really is the .Text. I've added a value to the .tag and then changed my select case to Textboxas.tag and now its reading the whole number and not just the first digit. Seems odd though....maybe .text forces it to be seen as string therefore therefore matching whatever comes first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast the `TextStatas` to an integer using `CInt(TextStatas)`

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub TestMethod1()

    Dim Arr_TextStat(5) As String
    Arr_TextStat(0) = "1"
    Arr_TextStat(1) = "2"
    Arr_TextStat(2) = "3"
    Arr_TextStat(3) = "4"
    Arr_TextStat(4) = "9"
    Arr_TextStat(5) = "20"

    Dim backColor As Color = Color.AntiqueWhite

    For Each TextStatas In Arr_TextStat
        Select Case CInt(TextStatas)
            Case > 4
                backColor = Color.Green

            Case > 3
                backColor = Color.GreenYellow

            Case > 2
                backColor = Color.Gold

            Case > 1
                backColor = Color.DarkOrange

            Case > 0
                backColor = Color.Red

            Case 0
                backColor = Color.Red

        End Select

        Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", TextStatas, backColor)
    Next
End Sub
```

Gives these results:

```
Debug Trace:
1 - Color [Red]
2 - Color [DarkOrange]
3 - Color [Gold]
4 - Color [GreenYellow]
9 - Color [Green]
20 - Color [Green]
```

Comment: JayV why are you adding specifically 9 and 20 to the array?

Comment: @OMGSOMETAL purely as a test to show/prove that it works as expected (or at least how I think you want it to work). If the values of 9 or 20 are in the textbox, then you would want to get the Color.Green set as the backColor. As you didn't suggest any values for the array, I made a guess based on what you wrote

Comment: The values are assigned from a database to textboxes and it might vary from 0 to thousands.

Comment: Okay, given the inputs of 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 20, used as a quick testing sample - Is the result what you expect or something totally different?

Comment: Can't run it, it says Textstatas cannot be converted to integer on Select Case CInt(TextStatas) line

Comment: In your code, you will need to change that part to `CInt(TextStatas.Text)`. I used a regular String array instead of an array of TextBoxes

Comment: I've changed from .Text to .Tag and it did the job. I will try CInt(TextStatas.Text) as it seems cleaner than adding a .Tag on purpose

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string (the `.Text` property) to a number. Before VB makes the comparison, it must bring the values to a common ground.

Exactly how that is performed depends on the context, which is why it is advised to avoid loosely typed comparisons in the first place.

- If you are comparing a string variable with number-like contents to a number:

  ```
  Dim s As String = "26"

  MsgBox(s > 2)
  MsgBox(s > 3)
  ```

  VB will convert the number-like string to a number and then perform the comparison. The result will be `True` in both cases.

  And if `s` contains something that cannot be converted to a number, you will get a runtime error.
- If you are using a string variable as a source of a `Select Case` clause, then the opposite happens, and the values in the individual `Case` clauses are first converted to strings, and then the comparison is performed, regardless of whether or not the variable in question contains a number-like string:

  ```
  Dim s As String = "26"

  Select Case s
      Case Is > 3
          MsgBox("> 3")
      Case Is > 2
          MsgBox("> 2, but < 3")
      Case Else
          MsgBox("Other")
  End Select
  ```

  You will see `"> 2, but < 3"`, because `"26" > "2"`, but `"26" < "3"`.

  And it will work the same if `s` contains something that cannot be converted to a number (try this example with `s = "sdf"`).
- If you are comparing an `Object` variable to a number, it will be first converted to a number regardless of whether it is used directly or as a source of a `Select Case`:

  ```
  Dim s As Object = "26"

  MsgBox(s > 2)  ' True
  MsgBox(s > 3)  ' True

  Select Case s
      Case Is > 3
          MsgBox("> 3")  ' Displays
      Case Is > 2
          MsgBox("> 2, but < 3")
      Case Else
          MsgBox("Other")
  End Select
  ```

  And if `s` contains something that cannot converted to a number, it will be a runtime error in both cases.

That is why it did not work with `TextStatas.Text`, which is a `String`, but did work with `TextStatas.Tag`, which is an `Object`.

---

You should not rely on these rules, always use `Option Strict On`, and change the code to

```
Select Case Integer.Parse(TextStatas.Text)
    ...
End Select
```